# Chromium does not honor Fontconfig fallbacks? Can I set it for that? Or manually specify?

Tags: fonts, chrome

Chromium is not honoring font matching, set by Fontconfig.  If webpage CSS specifies fantasy, Chromium chooses Impact.

Fontconfig Configuration for fantasy,

```
$ fc-match fantasy
BauhausStd-Medium.otf: "Bauhaus Std" "Medium"
```

If webpage CSS specifies Helvetica, Chromium Chooses the default fallback font.

Fontconfig Configuration for Helvetica,

```
$ fc-match helvetica
HelveticaLTStd-Roman.otf: "Helvetica LT Std" "Roman"
```

Chromium Release tag,

```
17.0.963.56 (Developer Build 121963 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10
```

Is it possible to force Chromium to use the Fontconfig settings?  Or manually specify custom fallbacks?  I'm fully aware of the limited font configuration dialog, accessible in chromium preferences.

I appreciate any help received, in regards to my question.

Comment: I am having same problem. CSS is Tahoma. Fontconfig is FreeSans but Chrome chooses arimo